# Mouse cursor limits using newrez script

Tags: 12.04, mouse, xrandr

I'm using the [newrez script](http://linux-apps.com/content/show.php/?content=134686) on my netbook.

This script seems to draw an image to display with a wider resolution and then resides it to make it fit to my screen using Xrandr. This way i can have a 1280*768 resolution on my 1024*600 screen.

BUT my mouse won't move further than the virtual 1024*600 boundary on my newly 1280*768 displayed desktop.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

From Version 0.8 of newrez you can run:
`newrez-v`

From the newrez website:

> When you unpack this version, you will also get "newrez-v" which is an
>   entirely different approach. For those who cannot run newrez due to
>   driver issues, or because the latest Xrandr package traps the mouse in
>   a small rectangle (like my system), here is a solution while we wait
>   for these things to get fixed!

Comment: Thank you for the answer pl1nk, i tried the newrez-v and now I don't have any boundary issue since my cursor won't move xD, I can still click, use the mousewheel but not move. :3 any idea on how to fix it without loging out ? :)

Comment: @Shaihuld Do you have zenity and bc installed?

Comment: I do have them installed on this box

Comment: @Shaihuld: Well without login out (speculations) try to change your resolution to default resolution, check for running pids of newrez..